# Is it possible to open a file in File Explorer in my existing workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I right click on a file in File Explorer and select from the context menu "Open with Code", the file is opened in VSC all by itself.   Is there any way I can open a file and have it opened in my workspace?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the file from the Explorer directly into the workspace?

Comment: No, I mean when VSC is NOT already running.  I don't believe it is possible.